# SQL Server 2008 Import Data Wizard doesnt recognize Integer data for a column

Tags: sql-server, import

I have an excel sheet with 10 columns with headers. For a column I can have the data as "FF5" or else 620. The sheet name is IODE.

I am trying to import this data from SSIS Import data wizard into the database of table IODE.

On selecting source and destination in the wizard, when I click on PREVIEW DATA in Select Source Tables and Views window, I see the column with 620 as null. After importing this data, the table will have the NULL Instead of 620.

The data type for this column in table is nvarchar(50), I tried many data types like varchar(100), text/..

Only alpha numeric data is accepting.

I didn't write any code for this.. I am just trying to import data from excel sheet to a table.

Please help me in solving this

Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you have either FF5 or 620 as the values for that column meaning you have one or the other and nothing else or are there blank fields in that column as well?

Comment: Hi..For other than numerals (like 630, 130...) if its a combination of char's and numerals (like FF5, GR1) or if its purely FFE displays properly.. The problem is only wen the data is like 630, 140.. the field is NULL in the table after the data is imported to the database.
I tried diff datatypes for that column in the table. but its showing null for numerals.
Please help me
Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 0):

I tried reading the excel by using the Excel library reference in VB6.0.

As SSIS Import Wizard treats NUMERIC as NULL when the data is exported to the SQL Table.

This procedure works very well for the data insertion and also for the other database operations.

> Private Sub AccessExcelData()
>   On Error GoTo errHandler
>   Dim oXLApp As Excel.Application'Declare the object variable
>   Dim oXLBook As Excel.Workbook
>   Dim oXLSheet As Excel.worksheet
>   Dim strFileName As String
>   Dim lCount As Long
>   Dim strSCDName As String
>   Dim strICDName As String
>   Dim intSource_Index As Integer
>   Dim strInput_Port As String
>   Dim strLabel As String
>   Dim strSDI_CID As String
>   Dim intWordBitNO As Integer
>   Dim strFilter_Type As String
>   Dim strPgroup_Input As String
>   Dim strParagraph_Input As String
>   Dim strSQL As String
>   Dim sConnString As String
>   Dim cnTest As New ADODB.Connection
>   Dim rsTempRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
>   Dim objDataAccess As New FmmtDataAccess.clsDataAccess
>   Dim strxmlResult As String
>   objDataAccess.Intialize ConString

strFileName = App.Path & "\IODE.xls"

sConnString = "Server=uasql\commonsql;Database=accounts;Driver=SQL Server;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DSN=uasql\commonsql"

With cnTest
      .ConnectionString = sConnString
      .ConnectionTimeout = 4
      .CursorLocation = adUseClient
      .Open
End With

' Creating part of the excel sheet.
Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Create a new instance of Excel
oXLApp.Visible = False
'Donot Show it to the user
Set oXLBook = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(strFileName) 'Open an existing workbook
Set oXLSheet = oXLBook.Worksheets(1)   'Work with the first worksheet        oXLSheet.Activate

With oXLApp
For lCount = 2 To oXLSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
strSCDName = .Cells(lCount, 1).Value
strICDName = .Cells(lCount, 2).Value
intSource_Index = .Cells(lCount, 3).Value
strInput_Port = .Cells(lCount, 4).Value
strLabel = .Cells(lCount, 5).Value
strSDI_CID = .Cells(lCount, 6).Value
intWordBitNO = .Cells(lCount, 7).Value
strFilter_Type = .Cells(lCount, 8).Value
strPgroup_Input = .Cells(lCount, 9).Value
strParagraph_Input = .Cells(lCount, 10).Value

'strSQL = "Insert into XYX  () values (strSCDName ..... )   Here any DB related queries can be used
rsTempRecordset.Open strSQL, cnTest, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly                    Next
End With
' Closing part of the excel sheet.
oXLApp.Visible = False               'Donot Show it to the user
Set oXLSheet = Nothing               'Disconnect from all Excel objects (let the user take over)
oXLBook.Close SaveChanges:=False    'Save (and disconnect from) the Workbook
Set oXLBook = Nothing
oXLApp.Quit                        'Close (and disconnect from) Excel
Set oXLApp = Nothing
Exit SuberrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Screen.MousePointer = vbNormalEnd Sub

With this procedure the excel records can be read from vb applicatoin and can be inserted into existing table in the SQL database.
Thanks
Ramm